# unable to show view in centre if not data found in tableview iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableview in which I am showing data coming from server. Now If there is no data coming then I show a UIView which has a label and image which show no data found . I have created a xib file for view. Now when I get view from Xib and show as tableview background view then it does not show in centre. it shows on top.

```
  let emptyListView = EmptyListView.instanceFromNib() as! EmptyListView
        emptyListView.labelNothingFound.text = AppMessages.NoDataFound.noRestaurentFound
        emptyListView.center = tableView.center
        tableView.backgroundView = emptyListView
        tableView.separatorStyle  = .none
```

I also tried giving custom frames but it does not work. Please tell me what is the issue ?

Comment: I'm not sure it can work that way. What you could do, is use constraints and potentially another subview to center the contents on your xib.

Comment: Why don't you just add a subview to the tableView anchored to the center?

Comment: I face crash when I add the constraint. Can any body tell me how do I constraints code? I get error for view heirarchy

Answer (score 1):

You better make **extension** to **UIViewController**, that will make a sense so that you can use that xib where ever listing occurs.

Custom **UIView** class

```
import UIKit

class NoDataFound: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var noDataLbl: UILabel!
    var view = UIView()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    func setup() {        
        // setup the view from .xib
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        //view.frame = bounds
//        print(view.bounds)
        self.frame = view.bounds
        self .isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor .black
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)

    }
    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        // grabs the appropriate bundle
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "NoDataFound", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }
    func  showContent(msg:String){
        self.noDataLbl.text = msg
    }

}
```

Here i have created only lable in xib, u can add more UI elements, thats depends upon you.

**Extension**

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {

func showNoDataFound(currentView:UIView,content:String){
        let noView = NoDataFound()
        noView.tag = 12346
        noView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        noView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        noView.showContent(msg: content)
        currentView .addSubview(noView)
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: noView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: currentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: noView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: currentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    func removeNoviewTag(currentView:UIView){
        for view in currentView .subviews{
            if view.tag == 12346{
                view .removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

After your server response parsing
Call like below where ever you want to show **no data found**

```
if self.newsListObj.count == 0 { //your server array count
            self.removeNoviewTag(currentView: self.view)
            self.showNoDataFound(currentView: self.view, content: Contants.NoSavedArticleMessage)
            self.favCollectionView.isHidden = true //your list table or collection view
        } else {
            self.removeNoviewTag(currentView: self.view)
            self.favCollectionView.isHidden = false
            // reload your collection or table
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue and after alot of stuggle i comeup with this logic.

- Create custom view .xib file, add image and label as shown in screenshot.[image]

And add following code in its swift file and link outlets.

```
  import UIKit

    class NoJobsViews: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!

    class func instanceFromNib() -> NoJobsViews {
        return UINib(nibName: "NoJobsViews", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! NoJobsViews
    }

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

}
```

Add following method in your Utility class or in extension of UIViewController

```
  class func emptyTableViewMessageWithImage(message:String,image: String, viewController: UIViewController, tableView: UITableView) {
    let noJobsView = EmptyTableViewBackgroundView.instanceFromNib()
    noJobsView.imageView.image = UIImage(named: image)
    noJobsView.messageLabel.text = message

    tableView.backgroundView = noJobsView
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
}
```

Now write following lines of code in your TableView numberofRows Datasource method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if dataSource.count == 0 {
            Utility.emptyTableViewMessageWithImage(message: "No Job Found", image: kNoMyGig , viewController: self, tableView: tableView)
            return 0
        }

        tableView.backgroundView = UIView()


        return dataSource.count
    }
```